# Is there a name for this object? (Like a group, but the inverse is not necessarily a member of the set)

Tags: group-theory, terminology

A group is a set $G$, together with a binary operation $\cdot$ that

- is **closed** - if $f\in G$ and $g \in G$ then $f\cdot g \in G$
- is **associative** - $(f \cdot g) \cdot h = f \cdot (g \cdot h)$
- has an **identity element** $e$ such that $ef=f$ for all $f\in G$
- has an **inverse function**: for every $f\in G$ there exists $f^{-1}\in G$ such that $ff^{-1}=e$

I'm interested in a related concept where $f^{-1}$ exists, but isn't necessarily a member of $G$. This means that the identity function doesn't need to be in $G$ either.

As a simple example, consider the set $T$ of transformations $x\to x+a$, where $a>0$. Each element of this set has an inverse ($x\to x-a$), but neither the inverses nor the identity transformation are members of $T$.

So I'm looking for something very roughly like this:

A `<<insert name here>>` is a tuple $\langle G, H, e, \cdot \rangle$, where $G$ is the set of forward elements and $H$ is the set of reverse elements, and $e$ is the identity element. The binary operation $\cdot$ is:

- **closed** independently for $G$ and $H$. That is, if $f\in G$ and $g \in G$ then $f\cdot g \in G$, and if $f\in H$ and $g \in H$ then $f\cdot g \in H$.
- is **associative** (again independently for $G$ and $H$)
- has the **invertibility** property that for every $f\in G$ there exists $f^{-1}\in H$ such that $ff^{-1}=f^{-1}f=e$, and similarly for every  $h\in H$ there exists $h^{-1}\in G$ such that $hh^{-1}=h^{-1}h=e$.
- $(fg)^{-1} = g^{-1}f^{-1}$ for all $f, g \in G$, and similarly $(fg)^{-1} = g^{-1}f^{-1}$ for all $f, g \in H$.

It's very similar to a group, but where the elements are partitioned into (possibly overlapping) "forward" and "reverse" sets that might not contain the identity element. Note that if $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ then $fh$ might not be in either set.

In the example above, $G$ is the set of translations in the positive direction and $H$ is the set of translations in the negative direction.

I'm not sure what consequences this definition would have, but it seems like it might be a useful thing to define in the context of reversible dynamical systems. Does this concept already have a name, and if so where can I read about it?

Comment: But which set does $e$ belong to? And what other properties do you want to hold? In the current form, there does not seem to be any other connection between the two sets.

Comment: $e$ does not necessarily belong to either set; that's why it's included in the tuple along with the two sets. The connection between the two sets is (I hope, if I haven't made a mistake) defined by the invertibilty property. The elements of $H$ are the inverses of the elements of $G$, and vice versa.

Comment: To me it seems that what you want is $G \subseteq M$, where $M$ is a group, and $G$ is a semigroup with respect to the operation of $M$. In other words, $G$ is a subsemigroup of $M$. Searching with "subsemigroups of groups" on google might be helpful.

Comment: @spin yes, that might be the right way to look at it. I will read up on that idea.

Comment: @seaturtles I don't think that's right. Note that there's nothing stopping something from being a member of both $G$ and $H$.

Comment: Yes there is: if $a\in G\cap H$ then $e=aa^{-1}\in G\cap H$, contradicting where I said the subsemigroup $G$ doesn't have the identity. | Oh wait, are you saying in your original set up you are allowing $G$ and $H$ to overlap? It doesn't really make sense to say the elements are **partitioned** into "possibly overlapping" sets, and then to say that $G$ and $H$ may not exhaust all elements of the group: by definition, a partition means the cells are disjoint and collectively exhaustive.

Comment: @seaturtles yes, $G$ and $H$ can overlap, and are allowed to contain $e$ (but they don't have to).

Comment: But if $e$ is not in any of the sets, then your conditions do not add any information really. I can just pick some element in $G$ and say it is the "inverse" of all elements in $H$, and vice versa. Or I could pick a random element for each. There are no conditions that put a connection between those sets.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think I see what you mean. Can you take a look at the amended version of the invertibility axiom and see if that fixes it?

Comment: The addition does not change anything. Note that there is no connection between the operations on the two sets, and the "operation" that is involved in elements being inverse of each other is not related to either of them (it is defined only for a very select set of elements).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft again I think I see what you're saying, although I'm still not quite sure. It's possible that extra axioms might need to be added to fix that problem. I will think about it later, or you can feel free to make suggestions. I hope the intent is clear. If it isn't, I've added an example to the post that might help.

Comment: In general, you are putting a lot of weight between the difference between an element and its inverse. This distinction need not be clear. An alternative formulation (fitting you question title) is: When can a semigroup (or monoid) be embedded in a group? For commutative monoids, this can always be done when it is cancellative (the group is then called the Groethendieck group). In general, it is a very tricky question (though I think there is a complete description of it).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes, a semigroup embedded in a group might be the best way to think about it. I just hadn't thought about it that way when I asked the question. (I am very new to group theory.) I've added an extra axiom that might fix your issue.

Comment: This new addition definitely makes it more interesting. I will need to think a bit more about it to see what sort of thing might satisfy it (especially whether it still allows "degenerate" examples).

Comment: I believe you are looking for "positive cone" of an "ordered group". This is a stronger axiom system than yours, but also has much stronger results. (For instance, $G=H$ a group always satisfies your axioms, and $G \cup H \cup \{e\}$ is always a group, so you probably can't prove anything too exciting.) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_group

Comment: @JackSchmidt you might be right about the positive cone of a (partially) ordered group. However, I don't think that $G\cup H\cup \{e\}$ is always a group, because it isn't necessarily closed under the binary operation. For $f,g\in G$, $f\cdot g^{-1}$ might not be in $G\cup H\cup \{e\}$.

Comment: @Nathaniel: good catch. If you are good with $G \cap H \subseteq \{e\}$ and $G \cup H \cup \{e\}$ being contained in a group, then I think that the positive cone of a partially ordered group is what you want. In a linearly (fully) ordered group, $G \cup H \cup \{e\}$ is a group, but in a partially ordered group it may only be part of the group. However, I think your axioms could apply to a wider range of structures that are not subsets of groups.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be any semigroup. Define $H=G^{op}$ to be the semigroup with underlying set $G \times \{2\}$ but with the opposite operation, $(g \cdot_G h, 2) = (h,2) \cdot_H (g,2)$.

Define $(g,2)^{-1} = g$ and $g^{-1} = (g,2)$. Let $e$ be an element not in $G \cup H$, and define $(h,2) \cdot g = g \cdot (h,2) = e$. Then $\langle G,H,e,\cdot\rangle$ satisfies the axioms.

In particular, there is no restriction on the possibilities for $G$: it can be any semigroup, even those semigroups that cannot be embedded into any group.

---

I suspect what you want is to partially order your group, and define $G$ to be those elements greater than or equal to the identity, and $H$ to be those less than or equal to the identity. There will be some elements that are not comparable to the identity (all non-identity elements of finite order). For example, let $E = \{ x \mapsto Ax + b : AA^T = I, b \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$ be the group of linear isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and define $Ax + b \geq 0$ iff $A=I$ and $b \geq 0$ (meaning each entry of $b$ is greater than or equal to $0$). Then $G$ is the group of first orthant translations, $H$ are their opposites, and $G \cup H$ is only a small fraction of the total group (all rotations missing, all "mixed" translations missing).

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a set with binary operation satisfying associativity.

Then $G$ is called as semigroup. If $G$ contains idendity then it is called as monoid.

And semigroups need not to contain inverse of an element. But you want something more; $g^{-1}$ exist but may not be contained in $G$.

There is an example of such monoid.

Let $G=Q[x]-\{0\}$ be all nonzer0-polynomial over  $\text{ }  \mathbb{ Q}$. Then $G$ is monoid with respect to multiplication since multiplication of polynomials are associative and it contains $1$. But it does not contain inverse of $x^2+1$ as an example. But we know that inverse of it exist 
$$1\over x^2+1$$ which is not element of $Q[x]$. And if we add all inverse of elements to $Q[x]$ we will get a group.